# Textmate cmd + t search. How to include directories

Tags: textmate

I've always worked on small enough apps where I did not need to include a directory for Textmate `cmd + T` searching. Now I'm working on a huge app; swear to god it has 100 route files. Have no idea why.

So now if I to a search for `routes.rb`, I get 100 results. What I want is to include the directory `config` so I don't get so many results.

How can I include directors in Textmate `cmd + T` searches such as `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you will like the [GoToFile bundle](https://github.com/amiel/gotofile.tmbundle).  It's like Command-T but the search string is matched on the directory name and file name, not just on the file name part.

Answer (score 3):

I think 'Go To File' may work for you:
https://github.com/amiel/gotofile.tmbundle/

If you download it via GitHub, be sure to rename it to remove the hash at end of the extracted folder, so it's something like: 'amiel-gotofile.tmbundle' which you can just double click to install.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a folder from the Finder onto TextMate's icon in the dock, it will open that folder up as a project. You can then search the files within it using Edit>Find>Find in Project (Shift-Cmd-F).

Comment: Sorry that I don't understand the trouble. Do you want to find all the files with a particular name, then, using Cmd-T? Cmd-+ doesn't search in TextMate, and I don't see anything in the Roby or Ruby on Rails bundles that's tied to that key equivalent.

Comment: If you don't know cmd + t then you don't use textmate.

Comment: I know Cmd+T. That's why I was asking if that's what you meant. :) You mentioned Cmd +, which I took to mean either Cmd-= or Shift-Cmd-=. And if you do drop an folder on, Cmd-T will search within that folder. You can drag the folder from either the Finder or TextMate's project window to the TextMate icon in the dock and search only within that folder. For example, I have a folder that contains quotes.php and templates/quotes.html. Searching from the main project with Cmd-T shows both. Dragging the templates folder to the dock and searching only shows quotes.html.

Comment: But I'm looking for a way to open an app, with hundreds of sub folders and search for a file like this `app/lib/modules/models/submodels/supermodels/supermodel_fields/values` - it's a huge app and I need to be able to search for files like this.